# Gitlab CI Review Apps - get information from a deployment script back into a gitlab ci environment variable

Tags: gitlab, ansible, gitlab-ci

I use gitlab-ci for the automated tests. Now i extended it to allow for review apps deployed on digitalocean droplets via an ansible playbook.

This is working very well, but i need to get a variable from ansible to the .gitlab-ci - i can't find a way todo it.

.gitlab-ci.yml

```
Deploy for Review:
  before_script: []
  stage: review
  script: 'cd  /home/playbooks/oewm/deployment && ansible-playbook -i inventories/review --extra-vars "do_name=$CI_PIPELINE_ID api_git_branch=$CI_BUILD_REF_NAME" digitalocean.yml'
  environment:
    name: review/$CI_BUILD_REF_NAME
    url: http://$IP_FROM_ANSIBLE
    on_stop: "Stop Review"
  only:
    - branches
  when: manual
  tags:
    - deploy
```

the relevant parts from the playbook:

```
- name: Create DO Droplet
  delegate_to: localhost
  local_action:
    module: digital_ocean
         state=present
         command=droplet
         name=review-{{ do_name }}
         api_token={{ do_token }}
         region_id={{ do_region }}
         image_id={{ do_image }}
         size_id={{ do_size }}
         ssh_key_ids={{ do_ssh }}
         wait_timeout=500
  register: my_droplet

- name: print info about droplet
  delegate_to: localhost
  local_action:
    module:  debug
        msg="ID is {{ my_droplet.droplet.id }} IP is {{ my_droplet.droplet.ip_address }}"
```

So how can i get the droplet ID and IP to gitlab-ci?
(The ID is needed for the later Stop action, the IP to be viewed to the developer)

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "get it to gitlab-ci". Do you mean you want to set a gitlab-ci environment variable and have it be set OUTSIDE the CI job? Or do you mean your CI runner job needs to pick up a value INSIDE the CI job?    You want something to be added to the `script:` in the `Deploy for Review` section? You should be a bit clearer.   Perhaps you need to write a script that will parse the output of your ansible-playbook command and extract the values you obtained. Then do what you're going to do with it.

Comment: sorry for making my self not clear. i need a variable i have inside ansible playbook in the gitlab-ci context. I was hoping there may be a easier way as to parse the output of the playbook to get the value.

Comment: I improved your title for you.

Comment: @techraf https://www.google.at/search?q=gitlab+review+apps&oq=gitlab+review+apps

Comment: Thank you. I was stubbornly searching for the whole literal string, i.e. including CI.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ansible is a YAML-configured scripting tool itself and probably nearly turing complete automation scripting environment itself. Why not have it write a file called "./ip_address.sh" somewhere, and then dot-include that .sh into your gitlab CI?

The very top level of all this, in `.gitlab-ci.yml` would have this:

```
script:
   - ./run_ansible.sh ./out/run_file_generated_from_ansible.sh
   - . ./out/run_file_generated_from_ansible.sh
   - echo $IP_FROM_ANSIBLE
environment:
  name: review/$CI_BUILD_REF_NAME
  url: http://$IP_FROM_ANSIBLE
  on_stop: "Stop Review"
```

Writing the two shell scripts above is left as an exercise to the reader. The magic happens inside the Ansible "playbook" which is really just a script, where YOU "export a variable to disk" with filename "./out/run_file_generate_from_ansible.sh".

What you didn't make clear is what you need to do in Gitlab-CI with that variable and where it ends up, and what happens next. So above, I'm just showing a way you could "export" via a temporary on-disk-file, an IP address.

You could save that exported value as an artifact and capture it in other stages as well, so such "artifact-exports" can be passed among stages, if you put them all in a directory called `./out` and then declare an artifacts statement in gitlab-ci.yml.

Comment: Thanks for answering. Unfortunatly this will not work. see the ansible script creates an digitalocean droplet. i can dump the variables on this host, this would work, but i need them on the runner. i only see two ways - first grep the playbook output. second store a variables file in the droplet, ssh in copy it to the runner - but this will also not work because i dont have the ip of the droplet in the runner context :-)

Comment: i solved the ip problem using dynamic dns hosts via amazon route53 (just using the build id for it) but i still need the droplet ID to have the review app beeing destroyed.

ah nevermind - i will have to store this file on the runner via a local_action

Comment: i solved it - i dont need it in the .gitlab-ci.yml i need it in a different playbook (called `on_stop`) so i add a facts file after the creation, which in turn is gathered in the destroy playbook. as i have a hostname based on the pipeline id i know to which host to connect to fetch that information.

Comment: You can answer your own question and share a few code fragments if you like. I wont be sad if you accept your own answer.

Comment: i did so. would you mind take a look and tell me what you think?

Answer (score 1):

I finally got the setup to run. My solution uses AWS Route53 for dynamic hostname generation. (A problem i ignored to long - i needed hostnames for the different review apps)

Step 1:
Build the hostname dynamicly. For that i used `$CI_PIPELINE_ID` I created a subdomain on Route53 for this example we call it `review.mydomain.com`. The Ansible Playbook takes the IP from the create_droplet and creates a record on Route53 with the Pipeline id. `1234.review.mydomain.com`.

Now my .gitlab-ci.yml knows this hostname (because it can build it anytime) - no more need to get the Digitalocean droplet IP out of the ansible skript.

Step 2:
After review - the user should be able to stop/destroy the droplet. For this i need the droplet id i get when this droplet is created. 
But the destroy is a different playbook, which will run later - invoked by a developer.
So i need a way to store variables somewhere.
But wait, now that i know which host it is, i can just create a facts file on this host, storing the ID for me. when i need to destroy the host, ansible provides me with the facts, and i know the ID.

in the playbook it looks like this:

Role: digitalocean

```
---
- name: Create DO Droplet
  delegate_to: localhost
  local_action:
    module: digital_ocean
         state=present
         command=droplet
         name=oewm-review-{{ do_name }}
         api_token={{ do_token }}
         region_id={{ do_region }}
         image_id={{ do_image }}
         size_id={{ do_size }}
         ssh_key_ids={{ do_ssh }}
         wait_timeout=500
  register: my_droplet

- name: print info about droplet
  delegate_to: localhost
  local_action:
    module:  debug
        msg="DO-ID:{{ my_droplet.droplet.id }}"

- name: print info about droplet
  delegate_to: localhost
  local_action:
    module:  debug
        msg="DO-IP:{{ my_droplet.droplet.ip_address }}"

# DNS
- name: Get existing host information
  route53:
    command: get
    zone: "{{ r53_zone }}"
    record: "{{ do_name }}.review.mydomain.com"
    type: A
    aws_access_key: "{{ r53_access_key }}"
    aws_secret_key: "{{ r53_secret_key }}"
  register: currentip

- name: Add DNS Record for Web-Application
  route53:
    command: create
    zone: "{{ r53_zone }}"
    record: "{{ do_name }}.review.mydomain.com"
    type: A
    ttl: 600
    value: "{{ my_droplet.droplet.ip_address }}"
    aws_access_key: "{{ r53_access_key }}"
    aws_secret_key: "{{ r53_secret_key }}"
  when: currentip.set.value is not defined

- name: Add DNS Record for API
  route53:
    command: create
    zone: "{{ r53_zone }}"
    record: "api.{{ do_name }}.review.mydomain.com"
    type: A
    ttl: 600
    value: "{{ my_droplet.droplet.ip_address }}"
    aws_access_key: "{{ r53_access_key }}"
    aws_secret_key: "{{ r53_secret_key }}"
  when: currentip.set.value is not defined

- name: Add new droplet to host group
  add_host:
    hostname: "{{ my_droplet.droplet.ip_address }}"
    groupname: api,web-application
    ansible_user: root
    api_domain: "api.{{ do_name }}.review.mydomain.com"
    app_domain: "{{ do_name }}.review.mydomain.com"

- name: Wait until SSH is available on {{ my_droplet.droplet.ip_address }}
  local_action:
    module: wait_for
    host: "{{ my_droplet.droplet.ip_address }}"
    port: 22
    delay: 5
    timeout: 320
    state: started
```

Playbook digitalocean.yml:

```
---
- name: Launch DO Droplet
  hosts: all
  run_once: true
  gather_facts: false
  roles:
    - digitalocean

- name: Store Facts
  hosts: api
  tasks:
    - name: Ensure facts directory exists
      file:
        path: "/etc/ansible/facts.d"
        state: directory

    - name: store variables on host for later fact gathering
      template:
        src={{ playbook_dir }}/roles/digitalocean/templates/digitalocean.fact.js2
        dest="/etc/ansible/facts.d/digitalocean.fact"
        mode=0644

- name: Deploy 
  hosts: api
  roles:
    - deployroles
```

Playbook digitalocean_destroy.yml:

```
- name: Add Host to Inventory
  hosts: all
  vars:
    r53_zone: review.mydomain.com
    r53_access_key: "xxxx"
    r53_secret_key: "xxxx"
  tasks:
    - name: Get existing DNS host information
      route53:
        command: get
        zone: "{{ r53_zone }}"
        record: "{{ do_name }}.review.mydomain.com"
        type: A
        aws_access_key: "{{ r53_access_key }}"
        aws_secret_key: "{{ r53_secret_key }}"
      register: currentip

    - name: Remove DNS Record for Web-Application
      route53:
        command: delete
        zone: "{{ r53_zone }}"
        record: "{{ do_name }}.review.mydomain.com"
        type: A
        ttl: 600
        value: "{{ my_droplet.droplet.ip_address }}"
        aws_access_key: "{{ r53_access_key }}"
        aws_secret_key: "{{ r53_secret_key }}"
      when: currentip.set.value is defined

    - name: Remove DNS Record for API
      route53:
        command: delete
        zone: "{{ r53_zone }}"
        record: "api.{{ do_name }}.review.mydomain.com"
        type: A
        ttl: 600
        value: "{{ my_droplet.droplet.ip_address }}"
        aws_access_key: "{{ r53_access_key }}"
        aws_secret_key: "{{ r53_secret_key }}"
      when: currentip.set.value is defined

    - name: Add droplet to host group
      add_host:
        hostname: "{{ do_name }}.review.mydomain.com"
        groupname: api,web-application
        ansible_user: root

- name: Digitalocean
  hosts: api
  vars:
    do_token: xxxxx
  tasks:
    - name: Delete Droplet
      delegate_to: localhost
      local_action:
        module: digital_ocean
             state=deleted
             command=droplet
             api_token={{ do_token }}
             id="{{ ansible_local.digitalocean.DO_ID }}"
```

relevant parts from .gitlab-ci.yml:

```
Deploy for Review:
  before_script: []
  stage: review
  script:
    - 'cd  /home/playbooks/myname/deployment && ansible-playbook -i inventories/review --extra-vars "do_name=$CI_PIPELINE_ID api_git_branch=$CI_BUILD_REF_NAME" digitalocean.yml'
  environment:
    name: review/$CI_BUILD_REF_NAME
    url: http://$CI_PIPELINE_ID.review.mydomain.com
    on_stop: "Stop Review"
  only:
    - branches
  when: manual
  tags:
    - deploy

Stop Review:
  before_script: []
  stage: review
  variables:
    GIT_STRATEGY: none
  script:
    - 'cd  /home/playbooks/myname/deployment && ansible-playbook -i inventories/review --extra-vars "do_name=$CI_PIPELINE_ID" digitalocean_destroy.yml'
  when: manual
  environment:
    name: review/$CI_BUILD_REF_NAME
    action: stop
  only:
    - branches
  tags:
    - deploy

# STAGING
Deploy to Staging:
  before_script: []
  stage: staging
  script:
    - 'cd  /home/playbooks/myname/deployment && ansible-playbook -i inventories/staging --extra-vars "api_git_branch=$CI_BUILD_REF_NAME" deploy.yml'
  environment:
    name: staging
    url: https://staging.mydomain.com
  when: manual
  tags:
    - deploy
```

Comment: It's defnitely better to not rely on IPs and to use DNS,  it's better to leave your original question though so that people who are googling for "passing variable values" can find a technique.  But it's even better NOT to do that, so both answers here seem good.